# How to toggle a dynamically created textbox when dynamically created checkbox is checked and unchecked using javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]
    **I have dynamically created the table using javascript.**
    I have requirement to capture the values 'based on the checkbox'.
    on check the text field should be enabled and the corresponding row should be captured.

I tried

```
document.getElementById('chkIfSenior').onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('TEXTBOX').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

but I'm getting this error.

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null*

Below is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Add Checkbox dynamically to table cell using JavaScript</title>

  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
      font: 15px Calibri;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td,
    th {
      border: solid 1px #DDD;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 2px 3px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <script language="JavaScript">
    function MM_openBrWindow(theURL, winName, features) { //v2.0

      window.open(theURL, winName, features).focus();

    }
  </script>

  Product&ensp;<input type="text" id="myInput1" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Product.."> &ensp;Stock Type &ensp;<input type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Stock Type.."> &ensp;Batch&ensp;

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Batch.."> &ensp;Storage Type&ensp;<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Storage Type..">

  <br><br>

  <div id="container" style="width:1300px; height:500px; overflow:scroll;">

  </div>

  <br>

  <input name="btnSelect" type="button" id="btnSelect" value="Draw Bin" style="width:80px;height:30px" onClick="javascript:MM_openBrWindow('demo2.html','pop', 'scrollbars=no,width=350,height=210')"> &ensp;&ensp; <input name="btnSelect" type="button" id="btnSelect"
    value="Close Window" style="width:150px;height:30px" onClick="javascript:MM_openBrWindow('demo2.html','pop', 'scrollbars=no,width=350,height=210')">

</body>

<script>
  var listpagedetails = [];

  var request;

  var table = document.createElement('table');

  table.setAttribute('id', 'mTable');

  function myFunction() {
    var input, input1, input2, filter1, filter2, table, tr, td, td1, td2, td3, td4, i;

    input1 = document.getElementById("myInput1");
    input2 = document.getElementById("myInput2");
    filter1 = input1.value.toUpperCase();
    filter2 = input2.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("mTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


    var total = filter1 + filter2;

    //alert(total);
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {

      td1 = tr[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
      td2 = tr[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
      //alert(td1+td2);
      //  alert(total);
      //alert(td);
      td1 = td1.toUpperCase();
      td2 = td2.toUpperCase();
      if (td1 || td2 || td3 || td4) {

        // txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        //if (td1.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter1) > -1) {
        if ((td1 + td2) == (total) || (td1) == (total) || (td2) == (total)) {
          // alert(td1+td2);
          // alert(total);
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }


  var myApp = new function() {

    // An array of JSON objects with values.

    var jsondata;

    var data;

    var propertycontents;

    var di, pi;




    this.arrPack = [{
        '': '',
        'Product': '',
        'Product Short Description.': '',
        'Stock type': '',
        'Batch': '',
        'Storage Type': '',
        'Storage Section': '',
        'Storage Bin': '',
        'Avl.Qty': '',
        'Uom': '',
        'Batch in restr.-use': '',
        'Move Qty': ''
      },

      {
        '': '',
        'Product': 0,
        'Product Short Description.': 'Product0',
        'Stock type': '1',
        'Batch': '',
        'Storage Type': '',
        'Storage Section': '',
        'Storage Bin': '',
        'Avl.Qty': '',
        'Uom': '',
        'Batch in restr.-use': '',
        'Move Qty': ''
      },

      {
        '': '',
        'Product': 1,
        'Product Short Description.': 'Product1',
        'Stock type': '1',
        'Batch': '',
        'Storage Type': '',
        'Storage Section': '',
        'Storage Bin': '',
        'Avl.Qty': '',
        'Uom': '',
        'Batch in restr.-use': '',
        'Move Qty': ''
      },

      {
        '': '',
        'Product': 2,
        'Product Short Description.': 'Product0',
        'Stock type': '2',
        'Batch': '',
        'Storage Type': '',
        'Storage Section': '',
        'Storage Bin': '',
        'Avl.Qty': '',
        'Uom': '',
        'Batch in restr.-use': '',
        'Move Qty': ''
      },

      {
        '': '',
        'Product': 3,
        'Product Short Description.': 'Product3',
        'Stock type': '2',
        'Batch': '',
        'Storage Type': '',
        'Storage Section': '',
        'Storage Bin': '',
        'Avl.Qty': '',
        'Uom': '',
        'Batch in restr.-use': '',
        'Move Qty': ''
      },

      {
        '': '',
        'Product': 0,
        'Product Short Description.': 'Product4',
        'Stock type': '3',
        'Batch': '',
        'Storage Type': '',
        'Storage Section': '',
        'Storage Bin': '',
        'Avl.Qty': '',
        'Uom': '',
        'Batch in restr.-use': '',
        'Move Qty': ''
      }
    ]

    this.col = [];



    this.createTable = function() {

      for (var i = 0; i < this.arrPack.length; i++) {

        for (var key in this.arrPack[i]) {

          if (this.col.indexOf(key) === -1) {

            this.col.push(key);

          }

        }

      }



      // Create a table

      var table = document.createElement('table');

      table.setAttribute('id', 'mTable');



      var tr = table.insertRow(-1);



      for (var h = 0; h < this.col.length; h++) {

        // Add table header.

        var th = document.createElement('th');

        th.innerHTML = this.col[h].replace('_', ' ');

        tr.appendChild(th);

        tr.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#777;color:#fff;');

      }



      // Add new rows to the table using JSON data.

      for (var i = 1; i < this.arrPack.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);



        for (var j = 0; j < this.col.length; j++) {

          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);

          tabCell.innerHTML = this.arrPack[i][this.col[j]];


          if (j == 11) {

            var tBox = document.createElement('input');

            tBox.setAttribute('type', 'text');

            tBox.setAttribute("disabled", true);
            tBox.setAttribute("id", 'TEXTBOX');

            tabCell.appendChild(tBox);



          }

          if (j == 0) {

            // NOW HERE I AM CREATING AND ADDING A CHECKBOX TO THE TABLE CELL.

            var chk = document.createElement('input');

            var lbl = document.createElement('label');



            chk.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

            chk.setAttribute('value', 'yes');

            chk.setAttribute('id', 'chkIfSenior' + i);



            lbl.setAttribute('for', 'chkIfSenior' + i);

            // lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Yes'));



            tabCell.appendChild(chk);

            tabCell.appendChild(lbl);

          }

        }



      }



      tr = table.insertRow(-1); // Create the last row.



      // CREATE AND ADD CHECKBOX AND TEXTBOX TO A TABLE CELLS.




      this.td = document.createElement('td');

      // tr.appendChild(this.td);



      // var btNew = document.createElement('input');



      //  btNew.setAttribute('type', 'button');

      // btNew.setAttribute('value', 'Create');

      //  btNew.setAttribute('id', 'New' + i);

      //  btNew.setAttribute('onclick', 'myApp.CreateNew(this)');

      // this.td.appendChild(btNew);



      var div = document.getElementById('container');

      div.innerHTML = '';

      div.appendChild(table); // Add the newlly created table to the page.

    };





  }



  myApp.createTable();
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments,this did not work for me as the id for each row was different. I used the below code it worked but i'm not able to enable the textbox.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    var table = document.getElementById("mTable");
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    if($(this).is(":checked")){

        var activeRow = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        // document.getElementById("TEXTBOX")[1].setAttribute("disabled", false);
        $('#textbox' + activeRow).attr('disabled',!this.checked)
        // alert("Checkbox is checked.");
        alert(activeRow);
    }
    else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
        alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery selector for id should start with #, I have edited your answer to include #, observe this line `$('#textbox' + activeRow).attr('disabled',!this.checked)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to follow (unformatted code) but I guess the problem is that you are trying to get the checkboxes by the wrong ids.

```
document.getElementById('chkIfSenior').onchange = function() {...
```

But in your code you are setting the ids by:

```
chk.setAttribute('id', 'chkIfSenior' + i);
```

So your ids will look like: **chkIfSenior0, chkIfSenior1, chkIfSenior2...**

You can easily check that if you inspect the generated HTML. Happy debugging and please reformat your code

Answer (score 0):

The id `chkIfSenior` is not available, because ids are generated like `'chkIfSenior' + i`. You should use query selector like below,

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="chkIfSenior"]');
```

This will return list of all elements whose id starts with 'chkIfSenior'. And then you can iterate through all elements with help of simple for loop like,

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].onchange = function ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@as.if.i.code
Thanks,I have modified the code to

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

     var table = document.getElementById("mTable");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            if($(this).is(":checked")){

    var activeRow = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
   // document.getElementById("TEXTBOX")[1].setAttribute("disabled", false);
         // $('textbox' + activeRow).attr('disabled',!this.checked);
         // alert(document.getElementById('textbox1').enabled);
         // document.getElementById('textbox1').enabled = this.checked;
         // $('input[name="textbox1"]').attr('enabled', this.checked);
               // alert("Checkbox is checked.");
              //  alert(activeRow);
  //alert(document.getElementById('textbox1').enabled);
  $("#textbox" + activeRow).removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#textbox" + activeRow ).focus();



            }



            else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){



                alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");



            }

  });
```

This works

Comment: Good! But instead of adding new answer, you can edit existing answer.